# Basic Javascript for Quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables

I am creating a very basic quiz app using Javascript and was wondering what would be the best way to nest arrays/objects. I have done this before with just simple one level nesting but feel that this project might need more.

The quiz needs to have 5 questions with multiple answers. Each answer will have a points value associated with it. When the quiz has been completed it will take the average of the points to then give you a type ie. 'You nostly ticked A's', 'You mostly ticked B's' etc. Similar to the quizzes you get in magazines.

I believe it should be something like this:

```
var quizList = {
    "question": "What's your favourite Color",
    "answers": {
         ["a","Blue","2"],
         ["b","Green","4"],
         ["c","Red","6"],
         ["d","Orange","8"],
     },

    "question": "What's your favourite Animal",
    "answers": {
         ["a","Dog","2"],
         ["b","Cat","4"],
         ["c","Caterpiller","6"],
         ["d","Donkey","8"],
     }
};
```

Is this correct and if so how would I call the various array elements?

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object containing keys and values, some of which are arrays. See [**Working with  objects on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: This is kind of an opinion question and might be more suited to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct

Not really. That's not an array, it's an object literal which contains nested object literals and arrays. It also contains a pretty large problem; you're overwriting the previous question/answers keys with each new question/answer. You can't have two properties with the same name in an object. You've effectively done this:

```
{ a: 'b', a: 'c' }
```

Which is going to throw out the `'b'` and set `a` to `'c'`.

You probably need to rethink the structure so the top-level element is an array:

```
var quizList = [
  {
    "question": "What's your favourite Color",
    "answers": [
         ["a","Blue","2"],
         ["b","Green","4"],
         ["c","Red","6"],
         ["d","Orange","8"],
      ]
   }, {
    "question": "What's your favourite Animal",
    "answers": [
         ["a","Dog","2"],
         ["b","Cat","4"],
         ["c","Caterpiller","6"],
         ["d","Donkey","8"],
     ]
  }
];
```

> ... and if so how would I call the various array elements?

And you can't "call" these array elements. They're not executable code, they're dumb data. You need to *write a program* which uses this object as its input, and generates a `<form>` containing a series of `<input>` or `<select>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the the best way would be something like this:

```
var quizList = [{ 
  question: "What's your favourite Color",
  alternatives: [
    { letter: "a", text: "Blue", value: "2" },
    { letter: "b", text: "Green", value: "4" },
    { letter: "c", text: "Red", value: "6" },
    { letter: "d", text: "Orange", value: "8" },
  ]
}, { 
   /* other question */
}];
```

As pointed, your `quizList` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

This part is invalid:

```
"answers": {
     ["a","Dog","2"],
     ["b","Cat","4"],
     ["c","Caterpiller","6"],
     ["d","Donkey","8"],
 }
```

`answers` is an object (because of the `{}`), so it needs to have a key and a value. Perhaps you meant this:

```
"answers": [
     ["a","Dog","2"],
     ["b","Cat","4"],
     ["c","Caterpiller","6"],
     ["d","Donkey","8"],
 ]
```

Which is now an array which contains 4 nested arrays.

But I'd rather change it to this:

```
"answers": [{
         letter: "a",
         text: "Dog",
         value: "2"
     },
     //...etc
 ]
```

By making your options objects rather than arrays, you have a more robust way to get at the properties for each answer. So instead of:

```
var letter = someAnswer[0];       // is this the right index??
```

You can do this:

```
var letter = someAnswer.letter;   // now I know it's the right one
```

Your code will be much easier to maintain this way and you won't have to remember which index is which part of your answer.

Overall, I'd go with something like this:

```
var quizList = [{
        question: "What's your favourite Color",
        answers: [{ 
                 letter: "a",
                 text: "Dog",
                 value: "2"
            },
            // etc
        ]
    },
    // etc
];
```

Now at the top level `quizList` is an array of objects and each object has a property `question` and another property `answers` which is an array of objects with properties `letter`, `text` and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var quizList={
            "questions":[

              {
                "question": "What's your favourite Color",
                "answers": {
                               "a":{
                                     "text":"Blue",
                                     "point":"2"
                                   },
                                "b":{
                                     "text":"Green",
                                     "point":"4"
                                   },
                                "c":{
                                     "text":"Red",
                                     "point":"6"
                                   }
                                  "d":{
                                     "text":"Orange",
                                     "point":"8"
                                   }



                         }
               },
               {
                "question": "What's your favourite Animal",
                 "answers": {
                               "a":{
                                     "text":"Dog",
                                     "point":"2"
                                   },
                                "b":{
                                     "text":"Cat",
                                     "point":"4"
                                   },
                                "c":{
                                     "text":"Monkey",
                                     "point":"6"
                                   }
                                  "d":{
                                     "text":"Donkey",
                                     "point":"8"
                                   }



                         }
               }


          ]
    };
```

Try this with a json format.